# How to add a new Symfony2 project to the homestead?

Tags: symfony, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I am working on a project where I have to use a `Symfony2` project with `laravel5` on homestead.

How can I add `symfony2` project to the homestead?

Comment: So your really use a SF2 project with Laravel5? Do you know what Symfony2 is? So you use a laravel vagrant box with Symfony2?

Comment: @ELOISSIFIAhmed Why do you have to use laravel5 homestead for your Symfony2 project? that makes no sense, Can't you set up a normal vagrant box for your sf2 project?

Comment: @Xatenev I am working with a team on a project , want to use symfony2 in the backend and laravel in the frontend and setting up both frameworks in the same vagrant box .

Comment: I have one question.... WHY???? Why are you using 2 Frameworks witch depends on the same components? Why you use 2 Frageworks?

Comment: @ELOISSIFIAhmed Sorry, just no.

Comment: @Stony I know that laravel depends on symfony ,what im trying to do is using oroplatform  in the backend and share the same database with the backend and the frontend (laravel) !

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a vagrant box for SF2